# How to trim off left and right sides of image evenly as I reduce my screen size? (@media query)

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, resize, screen

I cannot find a way to trim off equal amounts of the left and right side of an image as I reduce my screen size. I am trying to add a @media query at the end of my css file to account for this; however, I don't know what to put inside of it. Currently, I have a .main container that holds my background image for my landing page.

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 770%;
    background-color: #170D2F;
    display: flex;
}

.main {
    position: absolute;
    width: 88%;
    height: 800px;
    cursor: auto;
    background: url(background.png);
    background-size: auto;
    top: 0;
    left: 6%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #170D2F;
}
```

I am trying to figure out what to put in here so that my image evenly resizes as I reduce my screen size to anything less than 1439px ...

```
@media (max-width: 1439px) {
   .main {
     ...
  }
}
```

I am trying to figure out how to reduce the background-size on both sides because currently when I reduce my page's size, it cuts off part of my image rather than reducing the size of it. Thank you!

Comment: Can you please post the associated HTML too, along with the image?

Answer (score 2):

you can achieve this without media query.

just edit `background` property in  `.main` class as follows:

`background: url(background.png) center no-repeat;`

replace `background.png` with your image source